# Proq Freq: By multiple categories

Tags: sas

I would like to find out if there is a way to do a freq on multiple categories, so that you end up with a overall total record and then the subcategories counts underneath it?

At the moment you would have to do 2 freqs and then 2 transposes and then set the data together. Below is the way I would normally accomplish this but is there a way to do it in 1 freq?

```
Proc freq data = data noprint;
tables CATEGORY*SUBCATEGORY     / out = Data1;  
tables CATEGORY                 / out = Data2; 
Run;

Proc sort data = DATA1 out = DATA1; by CATEGORY SUBCATEGORY; Run;
Proc sort data = DATA2 out = DATA2; by CATEGORY; Run;

Proc transpose data = DATA1 out = DATA1;
  var COUNT;  
  by CATEGORY SUBCATEGORY;
Run;

Proc transpose data = DATA2 out = DATA2;
  var COUNT;  
  by CATEGORY;
Run;

data Final;
  set DATA1 DATA2;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use PROC SUMMARY instead of FREQ, the TYPES statement enables you to choose which groups to summarise.  This just involves one step.

```
proc summary data=data;
class CATEGORY SUBCATEGORY;
types CATEGORY CATEGORY*SUBCATEGORY;
output out=want(drop=_type_ rename=(_freq_=COUNT));
run;
```

Comment: Is there also a way of automatically assigning CATEGORY variable name to the missing SUBCATEGORY rows that store the CATEGORY total counts
all in the same step, obviously I can assign them in the next data step, but was just wondering if it is possible all in one step?

Comment: I don't believe so, you could get into issues if the 2 variables are of different data types